# How to fix type 'int' has no len()?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, quad

I can't understand what's wrong with this code. Can someone help me please?
This is a Pareto type II integrand from 1 to infinite and a and b are the parameters of the distribution. TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() -> that's the error when I try to compute E

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from mpmath import *

def integrand(a, b, x):
    return x*a(b**a)/((x+1)**a)

a = 3                                                                                     
b = 2

E = quad(integrand, 1, np.inf, args=(a, b))
E
```

Comment: Where are you calling len() at? Also, I would avoid using single-letter variable names as it makes reading and understanding the code much harder. It's really hard to tell what you're actually doing here and I can't give a great answer.

Comment: This is a statistical problem. It's a Pareto type II  intergrand from 1 to infinite and a and b are the parameters of the distribution. TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() -> that's the error when I try to compute E

Comment: Why import `mpmath`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like import error to me ,both scipy and mpmath have implementation for quad method so to make the code work,will have to remove mpmath import statement.
I could run the code as below..getting overflow for large value of the upper limit

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
#from scipy.integrate import quad
from mpmath import *

def intergrand(a, b, x):
    return x*a*(b**a)/((x+b)**a)
a = 3                                                                                     
b = 2

E = integrate.quad(intergrand,1, 100, args=(a, b))
print(E)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
from mpmath import *
```

from your code.

[`mpmath`](https://mpmath.org/doc/1.2.0/) has a [`quad`](https://mpmath.org/doc/1.2.0/calculus/integration.html#mpmath.quad) function, so when you do `from mpmath import *`, you are overwriting the name that you imported from SciPy. You got the error `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` because `mpmath`'s version of `quad` expects the second argument to have the form `[a, b]`, but you passed in `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I do so it gives me another error: TypeError: integrand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: There are other problems; it would help if you tested the function shown in the question to ensure that it correctly returns a value when called.  When I do `integrand(1, 2, 3)`, I get an error, because there is a mistake in the expression being computed (probably a missing `*`).

Comment: Also, take another look at the docstring for [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html).  You'll see that it expects the integration variable to be the *first* parameter of the integrand function, so the signature of your integrand function should be `def integrand(x, a, b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check everything you pointed!